# EC2 Amazon Server getting stuck

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'va have my web hosted via a Amazon EC2.

Overall it's working fine, but sometimes (1 per hour aprox) it's like getting stuck. I'm not even able to write commands on the server console when it's on that status.

I moved from the micro instance to the small one expecting some improvement, but it's happening the same.

Any guidance where I should look to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on various factors.

**Areas you should be looking:**

- If you are not able to connect (SSH) to your instance: check your
  system log from your management console.
- If you are expecting slow response times: check your CloudWatch metrics from your console.
- Verify running processes on your instance. find out which process is taking CPU % / Memory %
  you can do this by `top` or  `ps -auwx`